# Laravel - Inserting users to database through vue.js component

Tags: database, laravel, security, vue.js

I am creating small project in Laravel. I made a small CMS based on vue.js (it is component based SPA application) and now I (as Admin) want to insert manually users to database (username, email, password, and boolean isAdmin) from vue's component.

And questions is how can I do that in **secure** way?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [vue-auth](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth) to handle this in my projects.  It injects itself into requests and responses through [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) or [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) HTTP client and allows for various authentication schemes.  [JWT](https://jwt.io/) is one popular option, I use [bearer authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229996/basic-http-and-bearer-token-authentication).

I use Rails for my APIs so I can't give advice on the Laravel end of things, but the basic flow is -

1. Vue client POSTS login request
2. Server responds OK and sends back JWT, bearer token, or some other payload for the client
3. Vue-auth processes this response and then injects it into future requests to the server, authorizing the request