# How do I send authorization header directly to client in Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, jwt

I'm trying the following:

I have a Spring Boot Application with spring security and jwt setup, on response from login I now want to set the Bearer jwt token directly into the clients headers, how can I do this?

Comment: in postman/curl: just by adding header with name `Authorization` and value `Bearer <your_token>` (where `Bearer` is literal, and `<your_token>` refers to the token value like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22229996/592355)); in browser: you can do it with a plugin like [mod header](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader-modify-http-hea/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=de)

Comment: Thanks, I knew that already, but can I automate that, so that when I get the response and I'm logged in the header is set automatically?